# checkeditems possible unintended reference comparison

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, checkedlistbox

I got this code although it works fine but its giving me a warning(possible unintended reference comparison) on the code (st.staff_name == chk). I puzzled why this is. Help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
    private void buttonCreateSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Body body = new Body
        {
            body_content = richTextBoxBody.Text
        };

        tnDBase.AddToBodies(body);
        tnDBase.SaveChanges();

        var genid = tnDBase.Genres.Single(g => g.genre_name == comboBoxGenre.Text);

        Article article = new Article()
        {
            article_name = textBoxTitle.Text,
            genre_id = genid.genre_id,
            status_id = 3,
            body_id = body.body_id
        };

        tnDBase.AddToArticles(article);
        tnDBase.SaveChanges();

        if (checkedListBoxWriter.CheckedItems.Count != 0)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x <= checkedListBoxWriter.CheckedItems.Count - 1; x++)
            {
                var chk = checkedListBoxWriter.CheckedItems[x];
                var staf = tnDBase.Staffs.SingleOrDefault(st => st.staff_name == chk);
                WriterLog writerlog = new WriterLog()
                {
                    article_id = article.article_id,
                    staff_id = staf.staff_id
                };
                tnDBase.AddToWriterLogs(writerlog);
                tnDBase.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting this warning because you're comparing a `string` to an `object`. Like all custom operators, the custom `==` operator for the `string` type (which compares the *value* of the string rather than whether or not the two strings have reference equality, which they might not) can only work when both operands are `string` references.

If you know that the items in `CheckedItems` will be `string`s, then just cast it to a string:

```
SingleOrDefault(st => st.staff_name == (string)chk);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that it is giving you the warning because you are taking the default value of 
`var chk = checkedListBoxWriter.CheckedItems[x];` and comparing it to a database item. Try and ask for a specific value `var chk = checkedListBoxWriter.CheckedItems[x].Value;` or force chk to be a string.